# Deleting pictures from both cards at the same time on D750

Tags: canon, nikon, sdcard, nikon-d750

After having a corrupt SD card ruin a bunch of shots for me a few weeks back, I got a D750 and configured it to save my shots to both SD cards.

The only annoying part of this is that when I delete one of my shots, it is only deleted from ONE of my SD cards.  I need to then select the image in the other card (which takes a while) and delete it again.

It would be great if deleting the image deleted it from both cards.

I've heard that the Canon 5DMkIV will delete both.  That and the addition of integrated GPS are really tempting me to return my D750 and switch away from Nikon.

Is there any way to configure the D750 like this that I'm not seeing?  Are there any other newer Nikon bodies (or firmware hacks) that will do this?

Comment: Not really an answer, possibly unhelpful, but it seems to me that the dual slot is a safety measure.  You delete from card A and the shot is still on card B.  If nothing goes wrong, you transfer card A and you're fine.  If card A is corrupted, you transfer from card B and yes, you have the extra shots that weren't deleted.  A minor inconvenience compared to not having a backup

If you accidentally delete a shot from card A, you have the ability to get that shot from card B, which is nice.

So seems to me what you consider a PITA could be considered a feature by others.

Comment: @MikeW True.  I could just ignore card 2 and just nuke it after I successfully transfer card 1's contents to my laptop.  But then I run the risk of running out of space on card 2 if I'm not careful. Also, it's quite easy to accidentally start managing the contents on card 2 when I meant to cull card 1.  I'd really like the firmware to only present a single image to me and have my actions affect both copies.

Comment: Not really an answer either, but culling shots in-camera can lead to increasing the risk of corrupted files in the first place. It has to do with the different file sizes of two images of the same resolution based on scene contents and how deleting and overwriting leads to fragmentation. This affects both raw and jpeg files for the vast majority of cameras. Memory cards are cheap. Save the culling until after you transfer them and then *format* the card in-camera before you use it again.

Comment: Assuming both cards are identical in capacity. If you do insist on in-camera culling, doing it on only one of the cards allows you to avoid overwriting the space used by the deleted files on card 1 (if the card's memory controller is well written and uses all of the card's *physical* memory locations - as opposed to *logical* memory location addresses -  before overwriting the previously used ones) by leaving everything on card 2. When card 2 is full you then change out both cards to two empty cards.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a pet-peeve of mine. I haven't found a camera that does it yet (Didn't try the 5D Mark IV) but none of the other dual-slot cameras (Nikon, Pentax, other Canon) do that. As you said, it is extremely annoying. This puts me off from using the dual-card in backup mode because I delete early and often.

Comment: The premise of this question is centred on deletion being necessary to avoid running out of space - but that is a symptom of insufficient storage.  This question strikes me as an X-Y problem and we should consider closing it.  One of the reasons for a backup is to keep things in case they are accidentally deleted as well as those that might be corrupted by a media fault.

Comment: James, your comment is based on a false assumption.  This has nothing to do with deleting to run out of space nor backing up to avoid accidental deletion.  I'm deleting because I don't want the image.  I'm using a second card for redundancy in case of card failure / corruption.

Comment: Just got a 750 and immediately noted the same annoyance. Oddly enough my older d7000 also had dual slots, but did delete from both cards at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

I have d600 and d3 nikons. Both cameras have two card slots, but neither really allows deleting same image from two cards at once.

Cards are represented in camera as continuous folders, which can be annoying. By that I mean that images go like (if cards are called A and B)
1A,2A,3A,1B,2B,3B. So you have to scroll through all hundreds of images to get ot B card: 1A..999A, 1B..999B

I shoot either RAW(A)+JPG(B) or JPG+JPG cloning. Shooting 1000s of images a day sometime doesn't really raise problem of deleting them one by one (which I think is what you want)

So, I would say that if you shoot few images, you don't need to delete anything, just format after transferring to PC or cloud. If you shoot tons of images, you probably won't have time to delete before transfer.